# ASP.Net WebSite not visible after deploying in Azure web app through CICD pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have deployed my ASP.Net web app application in the Azure web app through the CICD pipeline. Deployment gets succeeded. But, on opening mywebapp.azurewebsites.net, it is showing

> Hey, App Service developers!
>
> Your app service is up and running. Time to take the next step and
>   deploy your code.

What mistake I am doing?

Comment: it seems that you don't put the web application code to the app service during the deployment. How do you deploy the app in Azure Devops? Do you use Azure Web App task? Maybe you can share a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend a way to troubleshoot any app service deployments as follows.

1. Go to the Advanced tools left menu item on Azure app service as shown below

[image]

2. You will be taken to a website like the below. Follow the highlighted menu item as shown below to see the file system where you deployed your application.

[image]

[image]

[image]
3. Make sure your application files are there in the expected directory structure within **wwwroot** folder. If not, then you have not setup your CICD pipeline correctly. Make adjustments to your build and release pipeline accordingly. Follow the latest resource on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/targets/webapp?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) . Let me know you need further guidance.

Comment: @Abhishek : Could you accept this as answer if it helped you resolve the issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use one of these:

- WebApp on Windows
- Function App on Windows
- API App
- Mobile App

you may try marking flag `removeAdditionalFilesFlag`

[image: Azure App service deployment configuration]

More details you can find in the codumentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-web-app-deployment?view=azure-devops).

If you don't use one of above mentioned types you can consider this task - [Azure WebApp Virtual File System Tasks](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=geertvdcruijsen.GeertvanderCruijsen-Vsts-Release-AzureWebAppVFS).

I recommend you to try it out as it looks that original index file is still in place. This is why yoy may not see your page.